# make a interval start another interval

Tags: javascript, html, timer, local-storage, intervals

I have two window intervals that set a text and then remove a text, but after the first time they go, it sets them off balance. How can I make timer 1, start timer 2 after it finishes?

Timer 1:

```
window.setInterval(function(){
        save();
        document.getElementById('autosave').innerHTML = 'Game Saved';
}, 30000);
```

Timer 2:

```
window.setInterval(function(){
        document.getElementById('autosave').innerHTML = '';
}, 2000);
```

Comment: can you briefly depict the sequence you want to achieve ?
is it 30 / 32 / 62 / 64 / 94 / 96 ... ?

Comment: @lemonade the answers below explain what I was going for perfectly

Comment: alright, then it is 30 / 32 / 60 / 62 / 90 / 92 ... 
was just asking to make sure whether you want 30 secs distance after the timeout or between the intervalls ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need 2 intervals, you can just make your first interval start a `setTimeout` in which you remove the text after some time.

```
window.setInterval(function(){
    save();
    document.getElementById('autosave').innerHTML = 'Game Saved';

    setTimeout(function(){
        document.getElementById('autosave').innerHTML = '';
    }, 2000);
}, 30000);
```

Comment: Perfect, will make sure to make it an answer after accept answer cooldown.

Answer (score 1):

```
setInterval(function(){
    save();
    document.getElementById('autosave').innerHTML = 'Game Saved';
    setTimeout(function(){
        document.getElementById('autosave').innerHTML = '';
    }, 2000);
}, 30000);
```